# What is wrong with the following elasticsearch query?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to search fulltext on title and body and filter on answer count.
I read the [elasticsearch documentation for combining filters](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/combining-filters.html) and built this query.

```
"query": {
        "bool": {
            "minimum_should_match": "25%",
            "should": [
                {
                    "query_string": {
                        "query": "elasticsearch",
                        "analyze_wildcard": "True",
                        "fields": [
                            "body"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "query_string": {
                        "query": "test",
                        "analyze_wildcard": "True",
                        "fields": [
                            "title"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "constant_score": {
            "filter": {
                "query": {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [
                            {
                                "range": {
                                    "answer_count": {
                                        "gte": 0,
                                        "lte": 0
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It keeps giving me this error.

```
 RequestError: TransportError(400, u'parsing_exception', u'no [query] registered for [filter]')
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? I don't think that constant and bool filters can be at the same level.

Comment: I have some filters which should support wildcards (should have query_string query). So I want to put all the filters in a must array within constant_score->filter->bool. Where should I put the constant_score then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to write it like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "minimum_should_match": "25%",
      "should": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "elasticsearch",
            "analyze_wildcard": "True",
            "fields": [
              "body"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "test",
            "analyze_wildcard": "True",
            "fields": [
              "title"
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
       {
        "range": {
          "answer_count": {
            "gte": 0,
            "lte": 0
          }
        }
       }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have some filters which should support wildcards (should have query_string query). So I want to put all the filters in a must array within constant_score->filter->bool. Where should I put the constant_score then?

Comment: No need for constant score if you put all your filters in the `bool/filter` part.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I got rid of constant_score and put all the filters in query->bool->filter->bool->must array. It worked.